# duda funcionamiento de un camino de datos

Tags: ensamblador, ciencia-de-datos

tengo una duda con ejercicio que no sé por dónde empezar, es un ejercicio de camino de datos, y el enunciado pide explicar el funcionamiento del camino de datos de la foto, he buscado vídeos por youtube pero profundizan en conceptos que no entiendo mucho, empecé con este ejercicio porque tiene pinta de ser sencillo, no sé por qué conceptos empezar para explicar el funcionamiento, si los nombres de los registros implicados, el movimiento de datos, se agradece cualquier ayuda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: voy a quitar todas las etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver. poner etiquetas por poner no hace mas visible tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿No será esa la primera etapa del ciclo de vida de una instrucción? _"Fetching"_

Comment: podria ser.. por ese dibujo yo no interpreto nada de nada...

Answer (score 0):

Este camino de datos representa la primera etapa del ciclo de vida de una instrucción, la etapa **IF**(Instruction Fetching), en la que a partir del valor del **PC**(Program Counter) se accede a la memoria de instrucciones y se obtiene la instrucción correspondiente.

El primer elemento es el *PC*, un registro que contiene la dirección de memoria de la instrucción a ejecutar. Tras volcar el *PC* a la memoria de instrucciones, este se incrementa en 4(4 bytes, 32 bits) mediante el sumador que ves arriba. Incrementando el *PC* podremos repetir el ciclo en la siguiente instrucción.

El valor del *PC* se pasa a la memoria de instrucciones, que devuelve el valor de la instrucción residente en la posición de memoria que se introduce.